# OpenERP 7 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rounding'

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

Guys since I am new to OpenERP 7 and when I am trying to calculate the Taxed, Untaxed and Total Sales an error occur on my code

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rounding'
>
> return float_round(amount, precision_rounding=currency.rounding)

*sale_order.py*

```
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
    import time
    from openerp import pooler
    from openerp.osv import fields, osv
    from openerp.tools.translate import _
    from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT, DATETIME_FORMATS_MAP, float_compare
    import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp
    from openerp import netsvc


    class glimsol_bopas(osv.osv):
        _name = 'glimsol.bopas'
        _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']
        _description = "B.O.Pull-out Authorization Slip (BOPAS)"

        def copy(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
            if not default:
                default = {}
            default.update({
                'date_order': fields.date.context_today(self, cr, uid, context=context),
                'state': 'draft',
                'invoice_ids': [],
                'date_confirm': False,
                'client_order_ref': '',
                'name': self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'glimsol.bopas'),
            })
            return super(glimsol_bopas, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context=context)

        def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
            if vals.get('name','/')=='/':
                vals['name'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'sale.order') or '/'
            return super(glimsol_bopas, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)

        def button_dummy(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
            return True

        def _get_order(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
            result = {}
            for line in self.pool.get('glimsol.order.line').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
                result[line.order_id.id] = True
            return result.keys()

        def _amount_all(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
            cur_obj = self.pool.get('res.currency')
            res = {}
            for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
                res[order.id] = {
                    'amount_untaxed': 0.0,
                    'amount_tax': 0.0,
                    'amount_total': 0.0,
                }
                val = val1 = 0.0
                cur = order.pricelist_id.currency_id
                for line in order.order_line:
                    val1 += line.price_subtotal
                    val += self._amount_line_tax(cr, uid, line, context=context)
                res[order.id]['amount_tax'] = cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, val)
                res[order.id]['amount_untaxed'] = cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, val1)
                res[order.id]['amount_total'] = res[order.id]['amount_untaxed'] + res[order.id]['amount_tax']
            return res

        def _amount_line_tax(self, cr, uid, line, context=None):
            val = 0.0
            for c in self.pool.get('account.tax').compute_all(cr, uid, line.tax_id, line.price_unit * (1-(line.discount or 0.0)/100.0), line.product_qty, line.product_id, line.order_id.partner_id)['taxes']:
                val += c.get('amount', 0.0)
            return val

        _columns = {
            'delivery_date': fields.date('Delivery Date'),
            'cancel_date': fields.date('Cancel Date'),
            'auth_personnel': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Authorized Personnel'),
            'plate_no': fields.many2one('plate.no.create', 'Vehicle Plate No.'),
            'client_order_ref': fields.char('Customer Reference', size=64),
            'shop_id': fields.many2one('sale.shop', 'Shop'),
            'name': fields.char('Order Reference', size=64, readonly=True, select=True),
            'origin': fields.char('Source Document', size=64, help="Reference of the document that generated this sales order request."),
            'date_order': fields.date('Date'),
            'create_date': fields.datetime('Creation Date', readonly=True, select=True, help="Date on which sales order is created."),
            'date_confirm': fields.date('Confirmation Date', readonly=True, select=True, help="Date on which sales order is confirmed."),
            'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Salesperson', select=True, track_visibility='onchange'),
            'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Customer'),
            'payment_term': fields.many2one('account.payment.term', 'Payment Term'),
            'fiscal_position': fields.many2one('account.fiscal.position', 'Fiscal Position'),
            'company_id': fields.related('shop_id','company_id',type='many2one',relation='res.company',string='Company',store=True,readonly=True),
            'order_line': fields.one2many('glimsol.order.line', 'order_id', 'Order Lines'),
            'pricelist_id': fields.many2one('product.pricelist', 'Pricelist', readonly=True, help="Pricelist for current sales order."),
            'incoterm': fields.many2one('stock.incoterms', 'Incoterm', help="International Commercial Terms are a series of predefined commercial terms used in international transactions."),
            'picking_policy': fields.selection([('direct', 'Deliver each product when available'), ('one', 'Deliver all products at once')],
                'Shipping Policy', help="""Pick 'Deliver each product when available' if you allow partial delivery."""),
            'order_policy': fields.selection([
                    ('manual', 'On Demand'),
                    ('picking', 'On Delivery Order'),
                    ('prepaid', 'Before Delivery'),
                ], 'Create Invoice', help="""On demand: A draft invoice can be created from the sales order when needed. \nOn delivery order: A draft invoice can be created from the delivery order when the products have been delivered. \nBefore delivery: A draft invoice is created from the sales order and must be paid before the products can be delivered."""),
            'amount_untaxed': fields.function(_amount_all, digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account'), string='Untaxed Amount',
                store={
                    'glimsol.bopas': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, c={}: ids, ['order_line'], 10),
                    'glimsol.order.line': (_get_order, ['price_unit', 'tax_id', 'discount', 'product_qty'], 10),
                },
                multi='sums', help="The amount without tax.", track_visibility='always'),
            'amount_tax': fields.function(_amount_all, digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account'), string='Taxes',
                store={
                    'glimsol.bopas': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, c={}: ids, ['order_line'], 10),
                    'glimsol.order.line': (_get_order, ['price_unit', 'tax_id', 'discount', 'product_qty'], 10),
                },
                multi='sums', help="The tax amount."),
            'amount_total': fields.function(_amount_all, digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account'), string='Total',
                store={
                    'glimsol.bopas': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, c={}: ids, ['order_line'], 10),
                    'glimsol.order.line': (_get_order, ['price_unit', 'tax_id', 'discount', 'product_qty'], 10),
                },
                multi='sums', help="The total amount."),
            'currency_id': fields.related('pricelist_id', 'currency_id', type="many2one", relation="res.currency", string="Currency", readonly=True, required=True),
            'note': fields.text('Terms and conditions'),
            'signatory_prep_by': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Prepared By'),
            'signatory_ck_by': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Checked By'),
            'signatory_approved_by': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Approved By'),
        }
        _defaults = {
            'date_order': fields.date.context_today,
            'order_policy': 'manual',
            'state': 'draft',
            'user_id': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: uid,
            'name': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: '/',
        }

    class glimsol_order_line(osv.osv):

        def _get_uom_id(self, cr, uid, *args):
            try:
                proxy = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
                result = proxy.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'product', 'product_uom_unit')
                return result[1]
            except Exception, ex:
                return False

        def _amount_line(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
            tax_obj = self.pool.get('account.tax')
            cur_obj = self.pool.get('res.currency')
            res = {}
            if context is None:
                context = {}
            for line in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
                price = line.price_unit * (1 - (line.discount or 0.0) / 100.0)
                taxes = tax_obj.compute_all(cr, uid, line.tax_id, price, line.product_qty, line.product_id, line.order_id.partner_id)
                cur = line.order_id.pricelist_id.currency_id
                res[line.id] = cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, taxes['total'])
            return res

        _name='glimsol.order.line'
        _rec_name='order_id'
        _columns = {
            'order_id': fields.many2one('glimsol.bopas', 'Order Reference'),
            'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', domain=[('sale_ok', '=', True)], change_default=True),
            'description': fields.text('Description'),
            'product_qty': fields.float('Quantity', digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Product UoS')),
            'product_measure': fields.many2one('product.uom', 'Unit of Measure'),
            'remarks_reason': fields.text('Remarks/Reason'),
            'sequence': fields.integer('Sequence', help="Gives the sequence order when displaying a list of sales order lines."),
            'tax_id': fields.many2many('account.tax', 'sale_order_tax', 'order_line_id', 'tax_id', 'Taxes', readonly=True),
            'price_unit': fields.float('Unit Price', digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Product Price'), readonly=True),
            'price_subtotal': fields.function(_amount_line, string='Subtotal', digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Account')),
            'product_uos_qty': fields.float('Quantity (UoS)', digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Product UoS'), readonly=True),
            'discount': fields.float('Discount (%)', digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Discount'), readonly=True),
            'product_uos': fields.many2one('product.uom', 'Product UoS'),
            'th_weight': fields.float('Weight', readonly=True),
            'type': fields.selection([('make_to_stock', 'from stock'), ('make_to_order', 'on order')], 'Procurement Method', readonly=True),
        }
        _order = 'order_id desc, sequence, id'
        _defaults = {
            'product_measure' : _get_uom_id,
            'discount': 0.0,
            'product_qty': 1,
            'product_uos_qty': 1,
            'sequence': 10,
            'state': 'draft',
            'type': 'make_to_stock',
            'price_unit': 0.0,
        }
```

And here is my sale_order_view.xml

```
    <field name="order_line">
        <tree string="Sales Order Lines" editable="bottom">
            <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
            <field name="state" invisible="1"/>
            <field name="th_weight" invisible="1"/>
            <field name="product_id"
                context="{'partner_id':parent.partner_id, 'quantity':product_qty, 'pricelist':parent.pricelist_id, 'shop':parent.shop_id, 'uom':product_measure}"
                groups="base.group_user" 
                on_change="product_id_change(parent.pricelist_id, product_id, product_qty, False, product_uos_qty, False, name, parent.partner_id, False, True, parent.date_order, False, parent.fiscal_position, False, context)"/>
            <field name="description"/>
            <field name="product_qty"/>
            <field name="product_measure" options='{"no_open": True}'/>
            <field name="remarks_reason"/>
            <field name="tax_id" widget="many2many_tags" domain="[('parent_id','=',False),('type_tax_use','&lt;&gt;','purchase')]"/>
            <field name="price_unit"/>
            <field name="discount" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line"/>
            <field name="price_subtotal"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
    <group class="oe_subtotal_footer oe_right" colspan="2" name="sale_total">
        <field name="amount_untaxed" widget='monetary'/>
        <field name="amount_tax" widget='monetary'/>
        <div class="oe_subtotal_footer_separator oe_inline">
        <label for="amount_total" />
        </div>
        <field name="amount_total" nolabel="1" class="oe_subtotal_footer_separator" widget='monetary'/>
    </group>
```

Comment: As the error message states: `currency` seems to be `None`. There are no attributes on `NoneType`. Your order class copy seems to miss the priceliste feature, where the currency usually comes from. Please stop copying all your code into the questions, that's not helpful.

Comment: Check if the line `cur = line.order_id.pricelist_id.currency_id` in the function `_amount_line` of your model `glimsol_order_line` is returning anything (what value gets the variable *cur*).